# Is there a way to rebuild a stream builder when a variable that affects what stream it uses changes?

Tags: flutter

I have a stream-builder that uses a function to pick between two streams to use. A stream to pull all data and another stream that will only pull data using input from the user. I want the stream to refresh/rebuild each time the user changes their input. So every letter/number they add I want it to refresh with the relevant data. Or if its empty it'll just pull all data. I currently have it working, but you have to navigate away from the page and back to see the new data. What would be the best way to have the stream know that the variable changed in any way and it needs to run again to get the relevant data? Any help and/or pointers would be appreciated! Thanks!

This is where the user types in their input. Their input is saved into a TextController that is in a separate file that can be imported anywhere

```
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05,
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: Data.searchEditingController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Search",
                                hintText: "Search",
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
                          ),)),
                  ],
                ),
```

Here is a snippet of the stream-builder in a stateful widget where I call the function that will check if there is any user input to decide which stream to use

```
        body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
            stream: streamSelector(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              transactions = sortList(snapshot.data);
```

This is the function that chooses which stream to use based on if there is any user input. Data.searchEditingController.text is the variable that will change based on user input. Every time this changes I'm wanting this all to rerun so it can get fresh results.

```
 streamSelector() {
    if (Data.searchEditingController.text == "")
      return DataDBProvider.dataDB.getData();
    else {
      return DataDBProvider.dataDB.getSearchedData(Data.searchEditingController.text);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a listener to the controller?

Runnable example here: https://www.dartpad.dev/97dcaab2e48b1f939b81e9da1f45f142?null_safety=true

```dart
class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  final data = StreamController<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(processUserInput);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    data.close();
    controller.removeListener(processUserInput);
  }

  void processUserInput() {
    final input = controller.value.text;

    if (input.isEmpty) {
      data.add("fetch all data");
    } else {
      data.add("fetch only $input");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: StreamBuilder<String>(
              stream: data.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data ?? "");
              }),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 32),
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Search",
              hintText: "Search",
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```